# Invalid Celsius reading from Thermistor via Android ADK

Tags: android, arduino, adk

I'm on Project 8 in Mario Boehmer's book, Beginning Android ADK with Arduino.
I'm using a 10k thermistor with the following values but my temperature is reporting as 6531.0C which is obviously incorrect.

```
long r0 = 10000;
long beta = 4050;

// temperature in kelvin at at 25 celsius
double t0 = 298.15;
// value of second resistor
long additional_resistor = 10000;
// input voltage
float v_in = 5.0;
```

The readings off the serial monitor are as follows:

```
currentThermistorResistance: 128378.38
currentTemperatureInDegrees: -22.16
convertedValue: -221
voltageMeasured: 0.36
```

The full code is as follows:

```
#include <Max3421e.h>
#include <Usb.h>
#include <AndroidAccessory.h>

#define COMMAND_TEMPERATURE 0x4
#define INPUT_PIN_0 0x0

// Size: 5mm
// Resistance: 10KΩ
// Temperature: -30°C to +125°C
// Tolerance: ±10%

//-----
//change those values according to your thermistor's datasheet
// original
// long r0 = 4700;
// long beta = 3980;

//new
long r0 = 10000;
long beta = 4050;
//-----

// temperature in kelvin at at 25 celsius
double t0 = 298.15;
// value of second resistor
long additional_resistor = 10000;
// input voltage
float v_in = 5.0;

double r_inf;
double currentThermistorResistance;

/*
AndroidAccessory(const char *manufacturer,
                 const char *model,
                 const char *description,
                 const char *version,
                 const char *uri,
                 const char *serial);
*/

AndroidAccessory acc("UW MHCID",
             "HCID TempSense",
             "A temperature sensing android application",
             "0.1",
             "https://github.com/pdugan20/hcid-temp-sense",
             "0000000012345678");

byte sntmsg[6];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200);
  acc.powerOn();
  // changed from powerOn() to begin()
  // acc.begin();
  sntmsg[0] = COMMAND_TEMPERATURE;
  sntmsg[1] = INPUT_PIN_0;
  r_inf = r0 * (exp((-beta) / t0));
}

void loop() {
  if (acc.isConnected()) {
    int currentADCValue = analogRead(INPUT_PIN_0);

    float voltageMeasured = getCurrentVoltage(currentADCValue);
    double currentThermistorResistance = getCurrentThermistorResistance(voltageMeasured);
    double currentTemperatureInDegrees = getCurrentTemperatureInDegrees(currentThermistorResistance);

    // multiply the float value by 10 to retain one value behind the decimal point before converting
    // to an integer for better value transmission
    int convertedValue = currentTemperatureInDegrees * 10;

    sntmsg[2] = (byte) (convertedValue >> 24);  
    sntmsg[3] = (byte) (convertedValue >> 16);  
    sntmsg[4] = (byte) (convertedValue >> 8);  
    sntmsg[5] = (byte) convertedValue;
    acc.write(sntmsg, 6);
    delay(100);
  }
}

// "reverse ADC calculation"
float getCurrentVoltage(int currentADCValue) {
  return v_in * currentADCValue / 1024;
}

// rearranged voltage divider formula for thermistor resistance calculation
double getCurrentThermistorResistance(float voltageMeasured) {
  return ((v_in * additional_resistor) - (voltageMeasured * additional_resistor)) / voltageMeasured; 
}

//Steinhart-Hart B equation for temperature calculation
double getCurrentTemperatureInDegrees(double currentThermistorResistance) {
  return (beta / log(currentThermistorResistance / r_inf)) - 273.15; 
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?
My full code is here:
https://github.com/pdugan20/hcid-temp-sense

The thermistor in question is a 103 from the following datasheet:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwOn70drOiMfZ0FrZ2VsSVhKQ00/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please update the question to include the relevant code.  The link could disappear any time.

Comment: can you use serial monitor to debug what is the value of voltageMeasured, currentThermistorResistance, currentTemperatureInDegrees and convertedValue, so we can understand WHERE the problem begins. Also are you sure you have wired up everything correctly? see http://playground.arduino.cc/ComponentLib/Thermistor

Comment: @lesto certainly, I've included the values of those variables above. I'm fairly certain it's hooked up correctly.

Comment: Try substituting various ordinary resistors for the thermistor and see if you can simply get the reading to change.  Also make sure that if the thermistor is working against a fixed resistor in the circuit, that the value of that is correct and not off by a factor of 10 or 100.  Use good light when viewing the color bands, or verify with a meter.  Measuring the thermistor with a meter and comparing to its curve would be a good idea too.

Comment: @ChrisStratton you were right, I had the wrong resistor plugged in. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that was silly...
I was using a 1k resistor instead of a 10k resistor.
Replaced the hardware and it's now working correctly.
Thank you all for your help.